# Django AppsNotLoaded

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a python script to put some things in my database;

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
import django.db
from models import Hero #Does not work..?
heroes = [name for name in open('hero_names.txt').readlines()]


names_in_db = [hero.hero_name for hero in Hero.objects.all()] #ALready existing heroes
for heroname in heroes:
    if heroname not in names_in_db:
        h = Hero(hero_name=heroname, portraid_link='/static/heroes/'+heroname)
        h.save()
```

The import throws the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "heroes_to_db.py", line 4, in <module>
    from models import Hero
  File "C:\Users\toft_\Desktop\d2-patchnotes-master\dota2notes\patch\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Hero(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 105, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 237, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I know I can do `python manage.py --shell` and write the code for hand but to be honest, I dont want to. What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you looking to write your own [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/)?

Comment: @Sayse no, I'm looking to automate putting some data in the database.. Not necessarily make it a mgmt command.

Answer (score 1):

Django must configure all installed applications before you can use any models. To do this you must call `django.setup()`

```
import django
django.setup()
```

[From the documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded)

> This function is called automatically:
>
> - When running an HTTP server via Django’s WSGI support.
> - When invoking a management command.
>
> It must be called explicitly in other cases, for instance in plain Python scripts.

Comment: this gives me `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.` . I have set the environment variable to point to mysite.settings ..